# Applying Visa for Indian Parents, what Visa type to select

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I am applying for a UK visa for my Indian Parents from India through [this site](http://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk).
I need help in selecting the right Visa Type for them, would it be Family or Tourism?

[image: image of visa type drop downs]

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on the purpose of their visit, however those options look out of date so I don’t think that’s the correct application site. See https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/apply

Comment: Thanks Traveller, Has the application site changed recently .Few of my friends have earlier used the site I mentioned.

Comment: @Anindya Possibly around 3 years ago.